# A question about the number of intersections of lines in $R^{3}$

Tags: co.combinatorics, erdos, incidence-geometry

Suppose I have n lines in $R^{3}$ with the conditions that: no 3 lines in one plane, no 3 lines intersect at one point,  for fixed 2 lines, no 3 lines intersect these 2 lines at the same time.
what is the up bound of the number of intersections?
The up bound $n^{\frac{3}{2}}$ is a simple corollary of Guth-Katz's paper or one can prove it directly by algebraic method.
Is it possible to establish the up bound like $n^{\frac{4}{3}}$ or some better one?

The up bound will also be a up bound for Erdos's unit distance problem in $R^{2}$.

Comment: Maybe you could give a summary of or reference for the Guth-Katz paper and for the Erdos unit distance problem? 

Comment: The best summary of Guth-Katz paper I can think is the link in JSE's 
answer below,  for unit distance problem, one can find reference in the reference of http://www.cs.tau.ac.il/~michas/pst5.pdf.


Comment: If the lines are indexed by $1,\ldots,n$ and the set of lines intersecting line $i$ is called $A_i$, an upper bound is the maximum of
\[\sum_{i=1}^n|A_i|,\]
subject to $|A_i\cap A_j|\leqslant 2$ for all $i\neq j$. But it might be obvious that this bound is worse than $n^{3/2}$.

Comment: George Purdy (U. Cincinnati) is an expert on this general topic.  He is giving a seminar @NYU tomorrow on this.  Maybe contact him? http://www.cs.nyu.edu/~raghavan/geometry/spring11/Purdy.pdf

Answer (score 5):

[Terry's discussion of the Gutz-Katz paper on his blog](http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/11/20/the-guth-katz-bound-on-the-erdos-distance-problem/) gives an example showing that the Guth-Katz bound on incidences between lines in R^3 is sharp.  (Look right after the statement of Theorem 5.)

Your conditions are stronger than the ones there (e.g. you demand no more than 3 lines in a plane, where they only ask that no more than sqrt(N) lie in a plane) and I didn't check whether this example satisfy your conditions too.  But that example is surely a good place to start.

Comment: That example can not satisfy the constions in my question, in fact 
"for fixed 2 lines, no 3 lines intersect these 2 lines at the same time" is the most important condition in the question, it is not easy for me to think some example with many intersections but satify that condition....

Comment: I thought of your condition as saying something like "no three lines in a quadric" -- is that not right?  

What about n lines in a (singly) ruled surface of degree n^{1/2}?



Comment: It looks like "no five lines in a quadric" but not exactly same. n lines in a (singly) ruled surface of degree $n^{\frac{1}{2}}$ is a situation appeared if one try to prove the up bound $n^{\frac{3}{2}}$, but still the full strength of that condition will not be used...